# How to get boolean value from prototype of a variable

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to check the type of a variable. like below

```js
var a  = {a : '1'}
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(a));

var b  = [1,2,3]
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(b));
```

**output in MDN playground**

```
> Object {  }
> Array []
```

Now, I need to get boolean value based on the type.
for,
`Object` -> `true`
`Array` -> `false`
by using some kind of `if` conditions or any.

**How to get boolean value if the type of variable is object or array ?**

*I'm mainly looking for somecondition which checks for `object` type like `[3, 3] instanceof Array ==> true` checks for array*

Comment: `typeof a === "object" && !(a instanceof Array)`. For `b`, replace `a` with `b` in the previous expression

Comment: @Yousaf If I get a string or null this will not work. I'm not aware of the variable type as i'm getting it from server which is different everytime. for different type I need to return different values.

Comment: You can add more checks in the expression in my first comment. I don't think you can achieve the desired result using only a single condition because in Javascript, every type can act as an object.

Answer (score 2):

Use `... instanceof Array`

```
[3, 3] instanceof Array //> true
({"a": "b"}) instanceof Array //> false
```

Comment: Sorry this might work but I cannot use this. because for `([]) instanceof Object` or `({}) instanceof Object`, the output is `true`. So, the answer you gave will check only if it's an array or not. It will not check Object or not.

Comment: I'm looking for something which will check Object or not

Comment: Then just do `typeof(obj) == "object" && !(obj instanceof Array)`